# Jelastic API method SwapExtIps is missing after 5.3 update

Tags: jelastic

Tried to swap public IPs between nodes, but found method "SwapExtIps" disappeared from client and from [API documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/).

There is special note about method update in [5.3 Release Notes](https://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-53#multi-ip), but i found nothing about removal of this method.

I need to move public IPs, please advise!

Comment: Have you tried this API? https://docs.jelastic.com/multiple-public-ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it in such way:
https://[hoster-api-host]/1.0/environment/binder/rest/swapextips?envname=[string]&session=[string]&sourcenodeid=[int]&targetnodeid=[int]&sourceip=[string]&targetip=[string]